# Django - Learning Website Development with Django - Unable to determine if SyntaxError in views.py or urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to follow the tutorial in the book - Learning Website Development with Django (2008), Chapter 5, Page 72

I've received the following errors http://dpaste.com/1034485/ and I cannot figure out if it's in my views.py or urls.py file. (P.S Dpaste Link valid till 19th Mar 2013)

Similar problems to what I found are as follows:

1. http://markmail.org/message/w3s6sacserx2mwdi (Very Similar but cannot find answer)
2. [Django - AttributeError => 'set' object has no attribute 'get'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10406606/django-attributeerror-set-object-has-no-attribute-get?answertab=active#tab-top) ( Similar situation but the error was not the same. In this question - The error was actually in the code for the forms and setting the attributes for the text fields. I deleted them and now the code works fine. However, I'm not sure what he did and what code he edited.

My code as below:

views.py

```
def bookmark_save_page(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = BookmarkSaveForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            # Create or get link            
            link, dummy = Link.objects.get_or_create(
                url=form.cleaned_data['url']
            )

            # Create or get bookmark.
            bookmark, created = Bookmark.objects.get_or_create(
                user = request.user,
                link=link,
            )

            # Update bookmark title
            bookmark.title = form.cleaned_data['title']
            # If the bookmark is being updated, clear old tag list.
            If not created:
                bookmark.tag_set.clear()

            # Create new tag list.
            tag_names = form.cleaned_data['tags'].split()
            for tag_name in tag_names:
                tag, dummy = Tag.objects.get_or_create(name=tag_name)
                bookmark.tag_set.add(tag)
            # Save bookmark to database
            bookmark.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/user/%s/' % request.user.username)
        else:
            form = BookmarkSaveForm()

        variables = RequestContext(request, {'form' : form })
        return render_to_response('bookmark_save.html', variables)
```

Error Message:

```
> Environment:

> Request Method: GET

> Django Version: 1.4
> Python Version: 2.7.3


> 5. from bookmarks.views import *

> Exception Type: SyntaxError at /
> Exception Value: invalid syntax (views.py, line 56)
```

Apologies if the post is too verbose. Not sure what information is needed.

Note: Line 56 of views.py is 
`If not created:`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        # If the bookmark is being updated, clear old tag list.
   #    ↓ should be lowercase
        if not created:
            bookmark.tag_set.clear()
```

Comment: @user2208012 is that line 56 in your views.py file? If so, note how your exception told you which line to look at.

Comment: Thanks! Was searching through the whole night - Didn't realize that my "if" was of the wrong case. Will try that again and keep you posted by tomorrow if it works!